# How to modify or add Items in the JComboBox in Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

i'm beginner in java and i have to add items in a JComboBox of a small program.
So i open the source code with Netbeans 7.1 and in the design part i right-clicked the JComboBox and then clicked the Properties.

In Properties windows i saw lines:
model = user code

```
SelectedIndex = -1

SelectedItem = null

ToolTipText = null
```

Question:
Why i didn't see all the items names or where can i saw see them?
I tried in the source code, there is nothing about Items names.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Since you're a beginner, you should go through the Swing tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html and code everything in the tutorial without using a GUI builder.  Once you understand how Swing components work together, then you may use the GUI builder.

Comment: I would recommend nobody to use a designer for learning Swing. If you really want to learn it then use tutorials, example code, read javadocs. Any of these will help you learn faster than a designer.

Comment: Actually, I disagree.  Looking at the code output from a GUI Builder can be quite instructive... as long as you take it with a grain of salt and don't assume it's the ONLY way to do things.

Comment: OK if i see swing tutorial, there are very simple exemple but for my problem, i don't see there

Comment: Don't overlook the [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#eg).

Comment: @JimGarrison _Looking at the code output from a GUI Builder can be quite instructive_ - for seeing how _not_ to do it :-)

Answer (score 1):

In netbeans:

After opening properties for your JComboBox you should see a window like below, just type all the items into the box next to model, and seperate them with commas " , " like this:
[image]